# How can manage other heroku app in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there is any way to manage other heroku app, via using api in my heroku rails application.
I have to start/stop/restart other heroku application.

how can I do that functionality via any api.?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue calls to the Heroku API to achieve this. It uses OAuth to authorize the requests.

See the docs for [Heroku Plartform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) or check out the [workless gem](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) for an example. The workless gem starts and stops worker dynos on demand to save you dyno hours.

The workless gem uses environment variables to store OAuth key/token; to manage more than one application it will make sense to store this information in a database.